# Display data for admin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `parent` table and a `child` table.

A `Parent` `has_many: children` and a `Child` `belongs_to:parent`.

A parent logs in and then add his children.

There is an admin field in the parent model, which, when set to `true`, sets a user as an admin.

I have an admin view page in which I want admin to be able to see all the parents and their children.

How is this possible? Below is the admin show page. I have created a join between child and parent.

parent.rb

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
end
```

child.rb

```
class Children < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Migration file to join table:

```
class CreateJoinTableParentChild < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_join_table :parents, :children do |t|
      t.index [:parent_id, :child_id]
      t.index [:child_id, :parent_id]
    end
  end
end
```

main_admin.html.erb

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
  <div class="content" role="main" id="main-content">
    <article>
      <div>
        <h1>Admin</h1>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Primary Parent</th>
                (displays all parents)
                <th>Children</th>
                (displays children belonging to that parent)
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>           
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So a `user` is a `Parent` and an "Admin Parent" ( a `Parent` where the `admin` flag is `true`) can see all the other `Parent`s and their children?

Comment: @engineersmnky yes right

Comment: who do we know what `user` is currently viewing this page? Or is that unimportant?

Comment: @engineersmnky i have added the route that if the user is admin, route him to the admin page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be something like this:

In the controller:

```
@parents = Parent.includes(:children)
```

In the view:

```
<% parents.each do |parent| %>
  <%= parent.id %>
  <% if parent.admin? %>
    <% parent.children.each do |child| %>
      <%= child.id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a join table your relationships should also be `has_and_belongs_to_many` for this to function correctly  ([Article](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3451-Has-Many-Through-and-Has-and-Belongs-to-Many-in-Rails-5) for more info)

Example:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :children, dependent: :destroy
end

# Note the singular "Child" 
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  # Note the pluralization because a Child can have more than 1 Parent
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parents 
end
```

Now if I understand correctly you are looking for something like

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def main_admin
    @parents = Parent.includes(:children).references(:children) 
  end
end
```

And then `main_admin.html.erb`

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
  <div class="content" role="main" id="main-content">
    <article>
      <div>
        <h1>Admin</h1>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Primary Parent</th>
                <th>Children</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <% @parents.each do |parent| %>
                <tr> 
                   <td><%= parent.name %></td>
                   <td><%= parent.children.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>                 
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>           
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will list the parent's name and the children's names joined with a comma.

**Update** (Per Comment):

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
  <div class="content" role="main" id="main-content">
    <article>
      <div>
        <h1>Admin</h1>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Primary Parent</th>
                <th>Child</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <% @parents.each do |parent| %>
                <% parent.children.each do |child| %>
                  <tr> 
                    <td><%= parent.name %></td>
                    <td><%= child.name %></td>
                  </tr>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>                 
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>           
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I display just one child in front of the parent name. if a parent has two children parent name then child name in the next like it should be parent name(same as before) and then name of the second child.

Comment: @above I have added application.html.erb for admin above in the question. I have another funding table. Parent logs in to add his children and then apply for funding for each child. funding table has child_id . Activity, organisation, activity start date are all fields of funding table. Can you help me with displaying the funding table data in front of the child to which it belongs too in the application.html.erb

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU that is a new question and should not be added to this question. Since this has been resolved please roll back your edit and add a new question if you have one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805826/view-for-admin-in-rails/50806277?noredirect=1#comment88618615_50806277 if you have a chance please help me out on this