# View for admin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a parent table, child Table, funding table. Parent logs in, add his children and then apply for funding for each child.

parent.rb

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :secondaryparents, dependent: :destroy
end
```

funding.rb

```
class Funding < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :organisations, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :child
end
```

child.rb

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent
    has_many :fundings, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Parent has a field as admin. if set as true parent acts as admin. application.html.erb is the view of admin. I am able to display all the primary parents and their children in front of each other. I need help with displaying the funding applications of the children in front of them.

application.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
<!-- .main_column_css -->
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <div class="content" role="main" id="main-content">
      <article>
        <div ><h1>Application Status</h1>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                   <th>Primary Parent Name</th>
                   <!--  <th>Financial Status</th> -->
                    <th>Child Name</th>
                    <th>Activity</th>
                    <th>Organisation</th>
                    <th>Activity Start Date</th>
                    <th>Date Submitted</th>
                    <th>Amount Requested</th>
                    <th>Funds Available</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
  <% @parents.each do |parent| %>
    <% parent.children.each do |child| %>
      <tr> 
        <td><%= parent.parent_1_firstname %></td>
        <td><%= child.firstname %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</tbody>      
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>           
      </article>
    </div>
    <!-- .content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

financial status, activity, activity start date, date submitted, amount requested,  funds available are all fields of funding table. Funding table has the child_id. child table has parent_id. Kindly help

Update

```
<% @parents.each do |parent| %>
    <% parent.children.each do |child| %>
     <% child.fundings.each do |funding| %>
      <tr> 
        <td><%= parent.parent_1_firstname %></td>
        <td><%= child.firstname %></td>
        <td><%= funding.type_of_activity %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You  wanna print all the fundings for each child? If yes, you can use HTML partial for each funding

Comment: I can print fundings for each child in child show table. but the problem comes when I try to print in application.html.erb which is for admin view. An undefined local variable error shows up.  The parent acts as admin when admin field is set to true and parent is directed to the application.html.erb page if he is an admin.

Comment: You don't have a question in there?

Comment: Can you post error which you are getting for undefined local variable?

Answer (score 0):

you can do child.fundings.each do |funding| and then do all the attributes for funding.

Comment: what comes back when you have that child object and do child.fundings ?

Comment: it is the funding application for a particular activity

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU If the fundings are undefined, you should include it in the query, like: `Child.includes(:funding)`

Comment: @AlvaroCantador I have included child.includes(:fundings) in the controller. The problem is I am running the following code and it just runs for one child and the next parent or their children doesn't show up. see the update above

Comment: you're only going to see something for the child if that child has at least one funding.